# Do I need to use synchronization for c++ unordered_map if I only add entries to the map and modify them, but don't remove?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a callback which gets invoked everytime a process is created or terminated.

Now I have a map that each entry is a process id, and it contains the process information. I set the process to be alive in process creation, and set it to be dead on the process termination. If a new process with a pid of a dead process gets created, I would just replace that old pid information with the new one.

For now assume that memory is not an issue in this scenario.

My question is, do I really need to use synchronization mechanism such as std::mutex to lock it evertime i want to modify an entry or add/remove in my scenario? If so, why?

Because I dont want to slow down this program unless I really have to, because speed is the biggest priority here.

Comment: The rule is: If you have a variable shared with 2 or more threads, and at least one of those threads modifies said variable, then you need synchronization.  Without you have a data race and UB

Comment: Adding an item can reallocate or move around data internally in the datastructure thus invalidating what another thread is working on. The general rule : If an API does not describe it is threadsafe explicitly it is not threadsafe. In this case you should use a reader/writer locks , see : [std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) so you can have at least multiple threads reading concurrently

Comment: Code speaks much better than "text" for programming questions. What you are asking for can be [really easily demonstrated](https://godbolt.org/z/E5z3voerj). And then likewise easily answered.

Comment: @pptaszni: When it comes to asynchronous coding, "my code works" should *never* be taken as a guarantee of anything. Code that is not provably thread-safe should not be assumed to be thread-safe even if your code seems to work.

Comment: @NicolBolas of course, the test I linked is supposed to show race condition (it fails for me most of the time). I only mean that a question with a C++ snipped is much clearer than a description of what the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the standard explicitly says that an interface of an standard library type is thread-safe (or you are always using `const` methods on that object), then such concurrent accesses to the same object are *not* thread-safe.

And no form of `map` has any particular statements in this regard. So all modifying accesses to the object are treated identically: it is a data race if two (or more) threads attempt to access the object and one of those accesses is modifying, unless you apply appropriate synchronization between the accesses.